# Does iCloud require any telephone land line infrastructure to send messages?

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, messages

If all phone lines are down (meaning a local or national phone line outage) and with all cell phone towers being down, is there a way that I could send a iMessage (or an SMS) to other iPhone users by using iCloud Service (your offsite server farm)?

I am trying to figure out if a Cloud-Push Manager could push my message to all receivers, who are registered.

Is Apple's iMessage proprietary text messaging platform a transmission system that allows iMessages to go directly via satellite to those iPhone subscribes? Even if all telephone land lines are down?

Answer (score 1):

iCloud depends on the internet for transmission of data. iPhones, unfortunately, aren't capable of being sat-phones at this point (by themselves). As long as both the sender and the recipient have internet access, and as long as both are using iMessage (not SMS), then the iMessage should successfully be sent and received.

There are obviously multiple ways to get internet through which your phone could be connected. As you are aware, one such way is through cellular towers (if functioning), or another option is through a wifi connection (but again, this must have a landline connection as well). It is possible to get internet through a satellite dish and then broadcast that connection via wifi to your phone.

Again, both the sender and recipient must have internet in order to be able to communicate with iMessage.

Comment: That's actually incorrect. Two phones connected to their wireless carrier that support iMessage can send them to one another without issues using 3G, LTE or equivalent. You don't need Wi-Fi at all. If for some reason iMessage cannot be sent to any party it will then default to SMS (provided this option is enabled). With wireless, if a party disconnects, that option is not available (as Wi-Fi can't send SMS). iMessage only depends on Apple's servers and of course a version of iOS that support it.

Comment: @cksum, perhaps I wasn't clear enough in my answer but I mentioned there are multiple ways to connect to the internet. The first option I gave was "through cellular towers" (3G, LTE, etc.). The OP was asking if it was possible to send a message when all landline is down. So, the reason I mentioned wifi (via satellite) is because that is would close to the only connection that should stay true despite massive landline failure. I also mentioned that both parties must have iMessage, which would infer they are using compatible hardware and software.